# If statement within a where clause utilizing varible to create variables

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking for a way to compare information from a MYSQL database in PHP utilizing the

following logic:

```
IF 1a+2a=200, then ma=100

ElseIf 1a+2a=101, then ma=1

Elseif 1a+2a=2, then ma=1

else ma=0

IF 1b+2b=200, then mb=100

ElseIf 1b+2b=101, then mb=1

Elseif 1b+2b=2, then mb=1

else mb=0
```

then taking `ma+mb > 100` to make it a match

i am looking to use this info in the where clause of the select statement.

i have a user that needs to use this info against other users in the db to determine a match.  essentially each user has a column name, a, that either has 100, 1 or 0.  we add the current user data with all queried user info from the database to determine a match.

I amusing MYSQL and php, and i have tried a number of scenarios and just can't sem to get it working, any help or best advice is welcome and thanks in advance.

the update table looks like this

user1

```
   A    b   c  d
   100  1   0  1
```

user2

```
   A    b   c  d
   100  1   1  1
```

i need to compare users to see if they match based on the above criteria which is if like columns are added up and eventually reach 101 or greater they are a match.  there are 34 columns in all.  User 1 would be the constant user, there could be more users other than user2, there will be user3,4 5 etc.

Comment: This question is unclear.  Are there 2 users, "a" and "b", in the same users table?  What is 1a and 2a, are those 2 columns under user 'a'?  Please give us an example schema so we know what you're working with.

Comment: yes there are two users, 1 and 2, the columns are a and b.

Comment: OK, so the users are 1 and 2.  You say columns 'a' and 'b' but in your question you say 'each user has a column name "a"'.  Is there one column or two?  It would really be very helpful if you should your table schema (SHOW CREATE TABLE users) and provided a clear definition of external information.

Comment: i added some updated table data and hopefully an idea of the desired result

Comment: ah, that helps a bit.  Are c, d releavant?

Comment: they are, but all we care about is reaching a count of 101. bcd could also be 100,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing here ends up being tricky because you are adding columns a, b, c, d instead of defining truly relational data.  You end up having to consider the sums all together, looping, in general not handling the data the way it was meant to be handled in a relational database, because a, b, c, and d are all handled together but are defined as separate fields of the records rather than being separate rows in a properly related table.

Nevertheless, what you are doing can be done, I *think* ( I'm still not sure I understand what you're going for), with something like this.

First, mostly for simplicity, I define a function to do your comparison between to numbers a1 and a2.  ( These aren't necessarily column a, just 2 of the same column for different users) - merely implements your comparison )

```
DELIMITER %
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `datacmp`( a1 INT, a2 INT ) RETURNS int(11)
    DETERMINISTIC
return CASE a1 + a2 WHEN 200 then 100 when 101 then 1 when 2 then 1 else 0 end; %
DELIMITER ;
```

now we need to create a table to query, with some data.  I just inserted a, b, c, d values randomly either 0,1,100.

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `a` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `b` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `c` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `d` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES 
  (1,0,0,0,1),  (2,1,0,0,0),  (3,100,1,0,0),
  (4,0,100,100,100),  (5,100,0,0,0),  (6,1,0,0,0),
  (7,100,0,0,0),  (8,0,0,0,0),  (9,1,0,100,0),
  (10,100,0,0,1),  (11,1,100,0,0),  (12,0,0,0,0),  (13,1,0,0,0),
  (14,100,0,100,1),  (15,0,100,0,100);
```

Then given what you've described about your logic, a query like this would do it:

```
select u1.id as u1, u2.id as u2, 
datacmp( u1.a, u2.a ) as ma, 
datacmp( u1.b, u2.b ) as mb, 
datacmp( u1.c, u2.c) as mc, 
datacmp( u1.d, u2.d) as md 
from users u1 join users u2 on u1.id <> u2.id  
having ma + mb + mc + md > 100;
+----+----+------+------+------+------+
| u1 | u2 | ma   | mb   | mc   | md   |
+----+----+------+------+------+------+
| 14 |  4 |    0 |    0 |  100 |    1 |
| 15 |  4 |    0 |  100 |    0 |  100 |
| 14 |  9 |    1 |    0 |  100 |    0 |
| 14 | 10 |  100 |    0 |    0 |    1 |
|  4 | 14 |    0 |    0 |  100 |    1 |
|  9 | 14 |    1 |    0 |  100 |    0 |
| 10 | 14 |  100 |    0 |    0 |    1 |
|  4 | 15 |    0 |  100 |    0 |  100 |
+----+----+------+------+------+------+
```

If you wanted to find users matching a given user, you could add it in as a where.

```
select 
  u1.id as u1, u2.id as u2,  
  datacmp( u1.a, u2.a ) as ma, 
  datacmp( u1.b, u2.b ) as mb, 
  datacmp( u1.c, u2.c) as mc, 
  datacmp( u1.d, u2.d) as md 
from users u1 join users u2 on u1.id <> u2.id 
where u1.id = 14 having ma + mb + mc + md > 100;
+----+----+------+------+------+------+
| u1 | u2 | ma   | mb   | mc   | md   |
+----+----+------+------+------+------+
| 14 |  4 |    0 |    0 |  100 |    1 |
| 14 |  9 |    1 |    0 |  100 |    0 |
| 14 | 10 |  100 |    0 |    0 |    1 |
+----+----+------+------+------+------+
```

Note that mysql functions are pretty convenient, but if they intimidate you, you can always make the query 10x longer and include the content of the function - adjusted for each column name - instead of defining and calling the function.

Comment: this is awesome!!! Dan, Thanks, i'm not to familiar with stored procedures, but it wasn't to hard to figure out.  SO i can run this on the db to get the correct results, how do i run this in a php script to call the procedure datacmp?  the select stament looks normal, but will php understand what datacmp is if called?  thanks again this looks perfect.  bt, the second one is what i was looking for with the where.

Comment: A query, as far as PHP is concerned, is just a string.  The function  ( I defined it as a function, not a stored procedure) does have to be defined, and executable by the user that PHP uses to connect to the database.  Functions and stored procedures have a quirky, but nifty, permissions scheme - if you run into issues, best post on stack overflow.